# "cannot convert to a pointer type" with accessing struct via pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

```
gcc -g -O2    struct.c   -o struct
struct.c: In function ‘secondfunction’:
struct.c:19:2: error: cannot convert to a pointer type
  firstfunction((void *)onedata->c,(void *)&twodata.c,2);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
<builtin>: recipe for target 'struct' failed
make: *** [struct] Error 1
```

I'm trying to use pointer when copying contents of of struct to another struct via memcpy. But when I transfer pointer to the struct into function I cannot cast it into the void.

```
struct one {
    char a;
    char b;
};

struct two {
    struct one c;
    struct one d;
};

void firstfunction(void *source, void *dest, int size)
{
    //memcpy(dest,source,size)
}

void secondfunction(struct two *onedata)
{
    struct two twodata;
    firstfunction((void *)onedata->c,(void *)&twodata.c,2);
}

void main()
{
    struct two onedata;
    secondfunction(&onedata);
}
```

Comment: As a side note, it's usually considered bad form to do `void main()` rather than `int main()`

Comment: Don't use `void *` without need. And don't cast to or from `void *`.

Answer (score 9):

You are missing an ampersand (`&`):

```
 firstfunction(&onedata->c, &twodata.c,2);
               ^
```

(I removed the needless casts).

Answer (score 3):

You want this:

```
void secondfunction(struct two *onedata)
{
  struct two twodata;
  firstfunction(&onedata->c, &twodata.c, 2);
}
```

You just forgot the `&` operator.

BTW: there is no need to cast to `(void*)` here.